# How to get list of all files and folders in ftp server (C++)

Tags: c++, ftp, ftp-client

I need list of all files and folders in ftp server.

Is there a similar command as NLST for the entire server, not just for the current directory?

I use PASV mode.
This is connect to server:

```
void create_socket(int &sock, const char* server_ip, const unsigned short server_port)
{
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

  memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));// zero out structure
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;// internet address family
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);// server IP address
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);// server port

  if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
  {
  }

  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
  {
    std::cout << "connect error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your current c++ code connect to the ftp server?

Comment: Did you check [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/line_based.html)?

Comment: You probably want some FTP client library. Use [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

Answer (score 4):

The full list of FTP service commands starts at Page 29 in [RFC 959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt).

There's no "List the entire content of the server" command; very probable it's so because of restrictions related to access permissions/control (search 'access control' through the rfc text).